# Reading file from Google bucket in Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to read file from google bucket though I am able to read it via spark-shell by including the gcs jar while going into spark shell. While submitting it via spark-submit it throws below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Splitter.splitToList(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Ljava/util/List;
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase$ParentTimestampUpdateIncludePredicate.create(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:780)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.createOptionsBuilderFromConfig(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:2130)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.configure(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1822)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.initialize(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1003)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.initialize(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:966)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2689)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2723)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2705)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:407)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getWorkingDirectory(JobConf.java:656)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:440)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:413)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1015)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1015)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anonfun$getJobConf$6.apply(HadoopRDD.scala:176)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anonfun$getJobConf$6.apply(HadoopRDD.scala:176)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getJobConf(HadoopRDD.scala:176)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1157)
        at com.google.reader.GoogleRead$.main(GoogleRead.scala:41)
        at com.google.reader.GoogleRead.main(GoogleRead.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:752)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I tried by excluding the guava dependency but still I am getting the above error. Below is the build.sbt file which I am using

```
import sbt.ExclusionRule
name := "GoogleFileReader"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.6.1" exclude("com.google.guava", "guava")
libraryDependencies += "com.google.cloud.bigdataoss" % "gcs-connector" % "1.6.0-hadoop2" 

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "activation", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org", "apache", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "google", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "esotericsoftware", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "codahale", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "yammer", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case "about.html" => MergeStrategy.rename
  case "META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "META-INF/mailcap" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "META-INF/mimetypes.default" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "plugin.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "log4j.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "pom.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The guava library actually used when running in the cluster is an older one that Hadoop depends on and is provided when the driver/executor starts. It comes first in the classpath, so this is why the more recent version your code depends on is not used; thus, the NoSuchMethodError.

You can try this solution (http://jhz.name/2016/01/10/spark-classpath.html) which basically indicates spark that the user classpath should be checked first and then the Hadoop Classpath. It uses the following spark config parameters:

```
spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true
spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true
```

Most likely you will get in other kind of troubles down the road as I did (java.lang.LinkageError; because of the classloaders that are used in this case).

The solution that helped me was to shade the guava version that my code is using so that it no longer conflicts with the one that Hadoop depends on.
See the response to this:
https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/spark-connector-user/8GCd8iQPy3c

It consists of adding this shading rule in build.sbt

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(  
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.**" -> "shaded.@1").inAll 
)
```

Make sure you update also the merge strategy for com.google:

```
case PathList("shaded", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
```

Comment: link provided is 404 page

Answer (score 0):

```js
package com.murphy

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
object GoogleStorageReader {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("GCS test")
      .master("local")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "E:\\mobSummaryDataIngestion\\spark-warehouse")
      .getOrCreate()
    val jsonKeyFile = "E:\\ConnsKPI scripts\\gcstest\\gcstest\\google_key.json"
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile", jsonKeyFile)
    val df = spark.sqlContext.read
       .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
       .option("sheetName", "Master 18")
       .option("useHeader", "true")
       .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "false")
       .option("inferSchema", "false")
       .option("startColumn", 0)
       .option("endColumn", 20)
       .option("skipFirstRows", 3)
      .load("gs://bucket-for-practice/MAXIS_CELCOM_IT_Masterlist-2018.xlsx"
    )

    df.show()
   }
}
```

Please find attached pom file for dependency.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.murphy</groupId>
  <artifactId>mobSummaryDataIngestion</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>mobSummaryDataIngestion</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>


  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
          <artifactId>google-api-services-storage</artifactId>
          <version>v1-rev158-1.25.0</version>
      </dependency> <!-- this is a maven cloud storage json api-->
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
      <version>1.92.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigdataoss</groupId>
      <artifactId>gcs-connector</artifactId>
      <version>hadoop3-2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigdataoss</groupId>
      <artifactId>bigquery-connector</artifactId>
      <version>hadoop3-1.0.0-RC2</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
          <version>27.1-jre</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
          <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
          <version>1.30.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
          <version>2.7.8</version>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.crealytics/spark-excel -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.crealytics</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-excel_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.17</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.20.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.murphy.MobileDashboard</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <!-- see http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin -->
          <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.0</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <jvmArgs>
                  <jvmArg>-Xss4m</jvmArg>
                  <jvmArg>-Xms512m</jvmArg>
                  <jvmArg>-Xmx4096m</jvmArg>
                </jvmArgs>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <!-- get all project dependencies -->
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.murphy.MobileDashboard</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>

          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>make-assembly</id>
              <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>

  </build>
</project>
```